# Windows Phone Application and Certificates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encryption, cryptography

I am developing a Windows Phone application which will be demonstrated in the Windows Phone emulator.

Now, my application communicates with a server which requires digital certificates.  Is it possible to bundle a self-signed certificate (public key only) along with a certificate (containing private key as well) into the mobile application?

Or can the Windows Phone emulator access certificates installed into the machine on which it is being deployed?